# I want to retrieve item_id from dropdown list to save a id to order table

Tags: asp.net

I have two tables named `item` and `order`. I have retrieved `item_name` in a dropdownlist. I want to save `item_Id` in the `order` table I have a field in `order` table which is linked in `item` table.

thanks for helping me in advance

Comment: You code is in asp.net or in mvc?

Comment: The only description is not enough. Please share you code with relevant details.

Comment: i have code in asp.net . i have not write a code because i don't know how to save the id i have only use design part